# Images in a tkinter Text widget

Tags: image, tkinter

This is more of a curiosity thing, but is it possible to insert images, for example screenshots, into a tkinter Text widget and then use them? 
Word processors such as Microsoft Word can handle screenshots in text, and I was wondering whether it was possible to replicate such a feature in tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

Text widget has an image_create method. See [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)